# Docker login to AWS ECR from GitLab CI fails with "dial tcp: lookup docker on x.x.x.x:53: no such host" when pulling docker:dind from ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, gitlab, amazon-ecr

I'm working on porting a collection of Docker images used for GitLab CI/CD building and deployment from Dockerhub to AWS public ECR.
Everything works as it should except for [the standard Docker image](https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/094faa88f437cafef7aeb0cc36e75b59046cc4b9/20.10/dind/Dockerfile) that we use as a Docker-in-Docker service.
The same exact image that works when pulled from Dockerhub fails to login when pulled from public ECR.

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
    build-push:
      stage: package
      image: public.ecr.aws/x/x
      services:
      - public.ecr.aws/x/docker-dind:20.10
```

```
$ aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL
> Logging in to Docker registry...
> error during connect: Post http://docker:2375/v1.24/auth: dial tcp: lookup docker on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host
```

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2  public.ecr.aws__*
172.17.0.2  public.ecr.aws-*
172.17.0.3  runner-*
```

Thank you.

Comment: This looks like a DNS or networking issue in (could be both) in your build container.

Comment: It looks like it’s resolving the name `docker` (from `http://docker:2375/v1.24/auth` URL) through `8.8.8.8` Google nameserver.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this? I am facing the same error.

Answer (score 26):

To resolve this problem just add on /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml a volume map to docker sock.

```
volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
```

Comment: And if you need network,. than add "privileged=true" to the /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml

Comment: This one did the trick in private gitlab-runners

Comment: What if the executor is kubernetes?

Answer (score 7):

When building docker image in gitlab-ci, you must add this (`dind` is for "docker in docker"):

```
services:
  - docker:dind
```

Comment: I had a different issue than the original question but the same error message brought me here and this was what I was missing. Thanks

Comment: This one did the trick in gitlab cloud builds

Answer (score 1):

As per gitlab [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#docker-no-such-host-error) when using a custom dind docker image the docker hostname is still expected. To fix this you need to add an alias in your gitlab CI config like so:

```yml
build-push:
  stage: package
  image: public.ecr.aws/x/x
  services:
    - name: public.ecr.aws/x/docker-dind:20.10
    - alias: docker
```

Also not sure about your setup but the convention is to add `-dind` at the end of an image. Therefore, it should be `public.ecr.aws/x/docker:20.10-dind`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @orban https://serverfault.com/users/190624/orb%c3%a1n-zolt%c3%a1n

Just add "privileged=true" to the /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml

for ex

```
 [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "ruby:2.7"
    privileged = true <- change this from false to true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a misconfiguration of your Docker environment. For some reason it seems to be resolving the name `docker` (from `http://docker:2375/v1.24/auth` URL) through `8.8.8.8` Google nameserver. That can’t work obviously.

Try to add `120.0.0.1 docker` record in your `/etc/hosts` - that *may* help.

Comment: Isn't 127.0.0.1 or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add `--docker-network-mode "host"` to the Gitlab runner config. Before doing that I got the following error (assuming "dind" is the hostname, not "docker"):

```
ERROR: error during connect: Get http://dind:2375/v1.40/info: dial tcp: lookup dind on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host
```